# JavaScript regex to replace a specific word with a line break

Tags: javascript

I have a number of strings coming back from the database and I need to separate them into 2 lines based on a specific word that the backend person can insert in the string. (The word or symbol can be anything.)

I have tried the following:

```
    var str = "some string some string space some string";
    str = str.replace(/space/g, "\n")
    console.log(str);
```

but the string still appears over one line only.

```
...

        var str = "some string some stringspacesome string";
        str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
        console.log(str);
        var screenHeight = (this.state.windowHeight -90) + 'px';
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <section className={"main " + this.state.color_name} style={{minHeight: screenHeight}}>
                    <div className="content-wrapper">
                        <div className="content" >
                        <h1>{str}</h1>

...
```

After the replacement, the `str` variable is going to be used as the contents of an h1 element.

Comment: This works when I test it on my machine.  Obviously, the string literally has to say 'space' though.

Comment: I guess it is important to know how you process the data afterwards. Console.log may vary between browsers. Maybe splitting each line in an array would be a good solution?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the console.

Comment: It works on mine as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string to be used as the contents of an HTML tag, then `\n` isn't the proper way to have it display on two lines. Rather, you'll need to use an html break tag of `<br/>`. You can either replace that into your strings, like this:

```
str = str.replace(/space/g, "<br/>")
```

Or for simplicity's sake, since you mentioned that the "space" string to replace can be anything, it seems like you could just skip the replacement altogether and use the desired replacement on the backend.

Comment: This is what I get: sdfsfsd <br/> sdgsgfgdf

Comment: And does that do what you want when injected into an `h1`?

Comment: nope, it needs to be over 2 lines with a br in between but the br gets considered as a string in the solution provided